# For the set $ S=\{0, 1, 2, ...., n-1\}$, count the number of times that $(n) \vert (ab-cd)$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I've been looking at how zero divisors of 2x2 matrices behave with modular arithmetic, and I've come upon an interesting pattern that I am trying to better understand.  Essentially, I'm looking for a way to count the number of zero divisors in modulus $n$ in the set of matrices over  $S = \{0, 1, 2, ... n-1\}$. So here is my question, which involves a specific case of when the determinant can be divisible by $n$ :

Say $S = \{0, 1, 2, ... n-1\}$ and $a, b, c, d \in S$, is there a method to count how many times that $n \vert (ab-cd)$?

Or in other words, how many times will $(ab-cd) \%  n = 0$?

Comment: To make the notation easier, let $S=\{0,...,n-1\}$, and search for $n|ab-cd$. This is equivalent to looking for $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ such that $ab=cd$.

Comment: @DonThousand Thanks, that makes it clearer. Edited the OP

Comment: Note: If $n$ is composite, a zero divisor need not have determinant equal to zero.

Comment: Let $n$ be a positive integer, let $R=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and let $f(n)$ be the number of zero divisors of $M_2(R)$. Then based on the oeis result https://oeis.org/A000252 (which is not hard to prove), we have
$$f(n)=n^4\left(1-\prod_{p\in S} \frac{(p-1)^2(p+1)}{p^3}\right)$$
where $S$ is the set of distinct prime factors of $n$.

Comment: For the number of $4$-tuples $(a,b,c,d)\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^4$ satisfying $ab-cd=0$, see https://oeis.org/A020478.